# how to handle greedydata to take custom word in a log line while creating grok pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

01-10-2022 14:05:11.584 INFO  - Destination IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 | Source System IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 | BrowserName:Chrome | BrowserVersion:105 | requestURI:/dashboard | Feature name:Dashboard | Application:null | SubFeature name:Line Check | UserId:tushar | ApiCalled:/ruambot/api/getGraph() | ApiStatus:Success | Login Time:01-10-2022 13:46:42

how to handle the word sub-feature name in greedy data

Comment: Why would you use grok instead of a kv filter?

Comment: Agree with badger, you should kv filter here.

Answer (score 0):

with grok filter split message into two parts and then apply kv filter for second part of the message

```
filter {
 grok {
   match => ["message", "%{GREEDYDATA:message_part1}\-%{GREEDYDATA:message_part2}"]
 }
 kv { 
  source => "message_part2"
  field_split => "|"
  value_split => ":"
 }
}
```